# Geometric/Intuitive Interpretation of Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

I refer to Schwarz Lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma).

Is there a geometrical or intuitive meaning of Schwarz Lemma that helps to understand or remember this result better?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I ran into this same problem taking complex analysis. The interpretation involving the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb D$ is geometric but I didn't find it particularly useful for intuition/memorization. I settled for some vague intuition involving steady state heat distributions.

Comment: @StanCoreyCarter Interesting. Can you elaborate a bit or provide a link? I am interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:D→D$ be analytic and $f(0)=0$ then (a)$|f(z)|$$\le |z|$ and (b)$|f'(z)|\le1$. Intuitively, thinking of $f$ as a linear approximation of some analytic function within unit disc, we have $f(z)=az$, $a\in C$ for which (a) is necessary as $Range(f)\subseteq D(codomain)$ and (b) is necessary for $f(z)$ to be a contraction map.

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 4):

The geometric interpretation of the Schwarz lemma is that a holomorphic map of the unit disk into the unit disk is distance nonincreasing with respect to the hyperbolic metric on the unit disk. This interpretation is due to [Ahlfors](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1938-043-03/S0002-9947-1938-1501949-6/S0002-9947-1938-1501949-6.pdf). See the [survey](http://www.ams.org/notices/199908/fea-osserman.pdf) of R. Osserman for references. S. T. Yau [later generalized](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373880?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) this to the context of biholomorphic maps from a complete Kähler manifold with Ricci curvature bounded from below to a Hermitian manifold with biholomorphic sectional curvature bounded from above by a negative constant. A proof of a more general result can be found in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.0527) of V. Tosatti.

Answer (score 0):

The best interpretation of the Schwarz lemma I've heard of (I believe) comes from [Eells and Sampson's article concerning harmonic maps](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373037?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). Indeed, let $f : M \to N$ be a holomorphic map between complex manifolds. The Schwarz lemma is a result of the maximum principle applied to the energy density $|\partial f |^2$. The energy density measures the extent to which $f(M)$ is stretched, i.e., how much tension (c.f., the notion of tension field for harmonic maps ;) ) when it sits inside $N$.

In particular, if $M$ is a curve of genus $g$ and $N$ is a curve of genus $g+1$, then $N$ is more hyperbolic than $M$. Hence, $M$ will be stretched when it's mapped to $N$ under $f$. Since holomorphic maps can't be stretched, $f$ will be constant.